# Dart2 - webdev serve in a docker container

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Running `webdev serve` in a docker container is not working.

I am running `docker run -p 8080:8080`

And in the container it says:

```
Serving `web` on http://localhost:8080
Serving `test` on http://localhost:8081
```

Do you know how to run this in a docker container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is likely due to the fact you are serving on localhost in the container. An easy way around this is to bind to all interfaces.

e.g. `webdev serve --hostname 0.0.0.0`